# typedef для функции

Tags: c++, typedef

Хочу создать ссылку на функцию так как очень длинная цепочка вызова каждый раз.

```
typedef void(*PlayerVP)(FVector&, FRotator&);
PlayerVP VP = &GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint;
```

В итоге ошибка:

> error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

Если забрать амперсанд, тогда другая ошибка:

> error C3867: 'APlayerController::GetPlayerViewPoint': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Сигнатура самой функции `GetPlayerViewPoint`:

```
void AController::GetPlayerViewPoint( FVector& out_Location, FRotator& out_Rotation ) const
```

Comment: `auto vp{&AController::GetPlayerViewPoint};` Только цепочку вызовов вам этот указатель на функцию не укоротит, так как для вызова придется вызывать `GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()` для получения объекта `AController`

Comment: @VTT а можно как-то сделать чтобы у меня была ссылка на функцию именно этого объекта?

Comment: При использовании встроенной объектной модели методы класса представляют собой одну и ту же функцию у всех экземпляров этого класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указатели на **функции** нельзя использовать с нестатическими **методами** ("функциями членами класса").

А как заметили в комментариях, использовать указатели-на-члены-класса здесь смысла нет. С ними код не особо короче.

```
auto mem_ptr = &AController::GetPlayerViewPoint;
(GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->*mem_ptr)(x, y);
```

Лучше использовать другой вариант - сохранить ссылку на последний объект в цепочке:

```
auto &con = *GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
con->GetPlayerViewPoint(x, y);
```

Или сделать лямбду:

```
auto vp = [&](FVector &x, FRotator &y)
{
    GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint(x, y);
};
vp(x, y);
```

Comment: Вариант с лямбдой отлично подходит. Спасибо.